# What halachot are affected by color blindness?

Tags: halacha, see-sight-vision-blind, choleh-sick, color

What halachot are affected if a person is colorblind? One probable example I can think of relates to the laws of *niddah* and checking emissions. Another less likely example would be the the halachic time defined by when a person can distinguish between leek-green and turquoise (though I doubt that this is really affected if a person is colorblind).

Note: There are various different types of color blindness, as described [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness). I am interested in how all of these affect halacha.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any mitzva per se from which a colorblind individual would be exempted.

However there are judgement calls that an expert (usually a rabbi) has to make, some of which involve color. As you'd said, one of them is the color of certain stains with regards to *nida*. I know of a color-blind rabbi who does all sorts of leadership roles for his congregation, but has to send all "stain" questions to a congregant who has training in this area. A similar, though far less-weighty one, would be the occasional question of "is my etrog kosher?"

The earliest time for tefilin and tallit is when there's enough light in the sky for the *average* person to discern colors, it doesn't vary by person. (Otherwise a blind man would never be obligated in tallit, when in fact he is.)